# Not able to set focus in text area when it becomes visible

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I need to set focus in a Textarea once it is visible. I have used .focus() method but it does not work. Also I have tried with setting "autofocus" property to true, it works in Chrome but not on IE and firefox.

Please find code below which I am using:

```
public static GetInstance(): angular.IDirective {
    {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    element[0].autofocus = true;
                }
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this even JavaScript?

Comment: No, it's TypeScript. But I think he means `export function` instead of `public static`.

Comment: It is typescript code.

Comment: Great. Tag it correctly please.

Comment: Way ahead of you, Praveen.

Comment: Based on my experience, some DOM events seem to be triggered before the changes in the DOM itself make it live. I'm yet to dug myself into the topic, but what virtually always solves the issue for me is using a `setTimeout` with 0 as the timeout value, and call the `focus` method from the timeout callback.